# Gnucash Quote data from other than Alphavantage

Tags: gnucash

As on today, Alphavantage seems to throttle 25 requests/day on free account.
As we see other provides like Fool/Fidelity Direct etc,
Can somebody help configuring gnucash quotes retrival with source other than Alphavantage (preferably Motley Fool/Yahoo_Json/ any other better sources?
Thanks